# Dynamic memory allocation of a structure

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to write a program in which is structure with two fields: integer and string. Next I need to write a function which dynamically allocates this structure and takes int and string as parameters to pass them down to allocated structure. This function will also return pointer to newly made structure. Second element of this program should be function which takes struct pointer as parameter, then prints all of the fileds on screen and then free memory of struct. This is the best I could come up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct str{
   int num;
   char text[20];
};

struct str* return_address(int *num, char *text){
  struct str* new_struct=malloc(sizeof(struct str));
  new_struct->num=num;
  new_struct->text[20]=text;
  return new_struct;
};

void release(struct str* s_pointer){
  printf("%d %s", s_pointer->num, s_pointer->text);
  free(s_pointer);
};



int main()
{
  struct str* variable=return_address(1234, "sample text");
  release(variable);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I couldn't make this program work. Even if compiled it crashes.

Comment: I guess, `new_struct->text[20]=text;` is not what you want

Comment: A few problems.  Here are two of them.  In your return_address function, you want 'int num', not 'int *num'.  Also, take a look at the line where you're doing this: " new_struct->text[20]=text;".  That should be strncpy(new_struct.text, text, sizeof(new_struct.text));  You might want to set the last byte of new_struct->text to '\0' to make sure it is null terminated, otherwise your printf might explode if the original string was 20 chars or more.

Comment: Warnings are not for fun. Enable and pay heed to them! Only ask after you have fixed them! (search for existing Q&A if you don't understand them). And **always** check the result of `malloc` and other functions which can report a critical error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your array is very small, also it's not dynamic at all. If you are allocating using `malloc()` anyway, why not allocate everything dynamically?
2. You cannot assign to an array.
3. The `num` member, which I suppose is meant to store the length of the "*string*", is being assigned a pointer, which is not what you apparently want. And also, the behavior is only defined in very special circumstances when you assign a pointer to an integer, the compiler should be warning you unless you turned off warnings.

Perhaps you want this,

```
struct string {
    char *data;
    int length;
};

struct string *
allocate_string(int length, const char *const source)
{
    struct string *string;
    string = malloc(sizeof *string);
    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;
    string->length = strlen(source);
    // Make an internal copy of the original
    // input string
    string->data = malloc(string->length + 1);
    if (string->data == NULL) {
        free(string);
        return NULL;
    }
    // Finally copy the data
    memcpy(string->data, source, string->length + 1);
    return string;
}

void
free_string(struct string *string)
{
    if (string == NULL)
        return;
    free(string->data);
    free(string);
}
```